# How to play WAV data right from memory?

Tags: python, wav

I'm currently working on a sound experiment, and I've come across one issue. I save an array of wave data to a .wav file and play it, but is there a way to skip this step and simply play the sound right from memory? I'm looking for a solution that will work cross-platform.

Comment: [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) maybe?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether your problem is with loading the file from memory only (but you know how to play it from python) or if you altogether don't know either of the two steps? [see comments to my answer to understand why I'm asking! :)]

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using the [wave library](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html), right?

The docs say:

> **wave.open(file[, mode])**
>
> If file is a string, open the file by that name, otherwise treat it as a seekable file-like object.

This means that you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
>>> import wave
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> file_on_disk = open('myfile.wav', 'rb')
>>> file_in_memory = StringIO(file_on_disk.read())
>>> file_on_disk.seek(0)
>>> file_in_memory.seek(0)
>>> file_on_disk.read() == file_in_memory.read()
True
>>> wave.open(file_in_memory, 'rb')
<wave.Wave_read instance at 0x1d6ab00>
```

---

**EDIT (see comments):** Just in case your issue is not only about reading a file from memory but playing it from python altogether...

An option is tu use [pymedia](http://pymedia.org//index.html)

```
import time, wave, pymedia.audio.sound as sound
f= wave.open( 'YOUR FILE NAME', 'rb' ) # ← you can use StrinIO here!
sampleRate= f.getframerate()
channels= f.getnchannels()
format= sound.AFMT_S16_LE
snd= sound.Output( sampleRate, channels, format )
s= f.readframes( 300000 )
snd.play( s )
while snd.isPlaying(): time.sleep( 0.05 )
```

[source: the [pymedia tutorial](http://pymedia.org/tut/play_wav.html) (for brevity I omitted their explanatory comments]

Comment: That will let you read a WAV file from memory, but it won't let you play it.

Comment: In case it's not clear, StringIO basically allows you to wrap memory buffers in file-like objects to work with MOST things that want files.

Comment: @icktoofay - Indeed. But I understand this is the problem the OP poster has: he can load [and play] a file from the disk, but doesn't know how to do to do the first bit (loading) from the memory... or did I miss anything?

Comment: @mac: The question asked how to play a WAV from memory, and your answer answered how to read it, but not how to play it.

Comment: @icktoofay - I took it that he know how to play it already, but reading your comment I see the ambiguity in the question... I dropped a comment to the OP.

Comment: pymedia works, but what kind of resources does it use? I'd really like to write my own.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a wav file with generated sine wave samples in memory and playing it on Windows:

```
import math
import struct
import wave
import winsound
import cStringIO as StringIO

num_channels = 2
num_bytes_per_sample = 2
sample_rate_hz = 44100
sound_length_sec = 2.0
sound_freq_hz = 500

memory_file = StringIO.StringIO()
wave_file = wave.open(memory_file, 'w')
wave_file.setparams((num_channels, num_bytes_per_sample, sample_rate_hz, 0, 'NONE', 'not compressed'))

num_samples_per_channel = int(sample_rate_hz * sound_length_sec)

freq_pos = 0.0
freq_step = 2 * math.pi * sound_freq_hz / sample_rate_hz

sample_list = []
for i in range(num_samples_per_channel):
  sample = math.sin(freq_pos) * 32767
  sample_packed = struct.pack('h', sample)
  for j in range(num_channels):
    sample_list.append(sample_packed)
  freq_pos += freq_step

sample_str = ''.join(sample_list)
wave_file.writeframes(sample_str)

wave_file.close()

winsound.PlaySound(memory_file.getvalue(), winsound.SND_MEMORY)

memory_file.close()
```